# pandas dataframe.to_sql throws error when writing to MariaDB

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, mariadb

When I try and execute the code below, python gives me a `mariadb.ProgrammingError: Cursor is closed` even though the data was successfully written to the db. I guess there is something wrong with returning the rowcount (see the full traceback below). Is this a possible bug or am I missing something?

**code sample**

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
conn_str = 'mariadb+mariadbconnector://user:password@localhost:3306/database_name'
engine = create_engine(conn_str)
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': ['A', 'B', 'C']})
df.to_sql('pandas_test_table', index=False, con=engine, if_exists='replace')
```

**traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2951, in to_sql
    return sql.to_sql(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 697, in to_sql
    return pandas_sql.to_sql(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1739, in to_sql
    total_inserted = sql_engine.insert_records(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1322, in insert_records
    return table.insert(chunksize=chunksize, method=method)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 950, in insert
    num_inserted = exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 858, in _execute_insert
    return result.rowcount
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 1113, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\cursor.py", line 1691, in rowcount
    self.cursor_strategy.handle_exception(self, self.cursor, e)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\cursor.py", line 846, in handle_exception
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\cursor.py", line 1689, in rowcount
    return self.context.rowcount
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 1439, in rowcount
    return self.cursor.rowcount
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\mariadb\cursors.py", line 541, in rowcount
    self.check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\mariadb\cursors.py", line 55, in check_closed
    raise mariadb.ProgrammingError("Cursor is closed")
mariadb.ProgrammingError: Cursor is closed
```

**package version**

```
mariadb==1.1.4
pandas==1.4.3
SQLAlchemy==1.4.40
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [bug](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONPY-222) in MariaDB Connector/Python.

It's already fixed in 1.1.5 (not released yet). If you don't want to downgrade to 1.1.3 you have to build 1.1.5 from source.

**Update from 2023-09-27**: After investigating bug [CONPY-269](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONPY-269) it seems the problem is in SQL Alchemy/Pandas: After closing the cursor with `cursor.close()` the property `cursor.rowcount` is accessed. This is in contradiction to [PEP-249](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/):

**.close()**
*Close the cursor now (rather than whenever **del** is called).
The cursor will be unusable from this point forward; an Error (or subclass) exception will be raised if any operation is attempted with the cursor.*

Comment: using 1.1.6 and still getting the same error. It has not been fixed as far as I can see.

Answer (score 8):

I had attempted Georg Richter's recommendation regarding installing MariaDB 1.1.5 from source or rolling back to 1.1.3 and was still receiving the error message.

Eventually, I came across this [documentation](https://www.zditect.com/code/python/mysql-and-mariadb-mdash----sqlalchemy-14-documentation------------.html) and had changed the engine DBAPI from

```
uri = 'mariadb+mariadbconnector://Username:Password@localhost/test'
```

to

```
uri = 'mariadb+pymysql://Username:Password@localhost/test'
```

And it worked.

Comment: this works perfectly on 11 Mar 2023

Answer (score 1):

#### 2023-10-29 Update

For anyone that lands here from a Google search, and is in a position where they can't/don't want to change from `mariadbconnector` to `pymysql`, this bug should be fixed in:

- `mariadb==1.1.8` (bug ticket [here](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONPY-269?filter=-2))
- `SQLAlchemy==2.0.22` (bug ticket [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/10396))

Answer (score 0):

Hummm... I'm using mariadb version 1.1.5.post3, but I get the same error. Just the last lines of the data insertion code, which doesn't raise any error in case I use the pymysql connector:

```
new_employee = {'id': '105', 'first_name': 'Joao',
                'last_name': 'da Silva', 'description': 'Lorem Ipsum', 'active': '1'}
emp = {k: [v] for k, v in new_employee.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame(
    emp, columns=['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'description', 'active'])
df.to_sql('employees', con=cnx, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

The error:

```
    raise mariadb.ProgrammingError("Cursor is closed")
mariadb.ProgrammingError: Cursor is closed
```

Just in case, I've tried to downgrade to the version 1.1.5 mentioned above (using `pip install`, not from the source). Other packages versions:

```
SQLAlchemy        1.4.46
pandas            1.5.2
```

P. S. Although we have this error, the data is inserted into the Maria DB table.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33672185)

Comment: Hi, @Jeremie When I created the comment above, I thought I was replying to Georg Richter. But I noticed after I made the comment to the general question in the topic. Should I just delete it? I think's an additional information to the answer that used the lasted MariaDB driver, but that doesn't work.

Comment: when responding to someone, you shall click the "add a comment" link following their post, not replying to the main question.

Comment: Yes, I've learned after. I am not sure if I should simply delete the mistake or not.

Comment: Okay, I just noticed I cannot comment a comment yet. (Except my own, I suppose)